# google+ login error. Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost"

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-plus, google-signin

I am applying google+ login in my website. but when i send data to my service to save it on database it gives me following error:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin `"http://localhost"` from accessing a frame with origin "https://apis.google.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.

my code is: this function fills the values in textboxes. and the values are getting filled correctly.

```
function signinCallback(authResult) {
if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
    gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function() {
        var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
            'userId': 'me'
        });
        request.execute(function(resp) {
            var googleId = resp.id;
            var name=resp.displayName
            isGoogleSignUp(googleId, function(res) {
                if (res) {
                    window.location = "profile.php";
                } else {

                    $("#loginPopup").css("dispaly", "none");
                    $("#signupPopup").css("display", "block");
                    $("#socialName").val(name);
                    //$("#socialMail").val();
                    $("#socialId").val(googleId);
                    $("#socialType").val("google");
                  }
               });
           console.log(resp);

           });
      });
} else {
    console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
}
}
```

This function gives error when called by submit button click-

```
function socialSignUp1() {
var urlString = "Service/socialSignup.php";
var form = new Object();
form.socialId = $("#socialId").val;
console.log(form.socialId);
form.type = $("#type").val();
form.name = $("#socialName").val();
form.mail = $("#socialMail").val();
form.phone = $("#socialPhone").val();
form.address = $("#socialAddress").val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: form,
    url: urlString,
    success: function(resultData) {
        if (resultData == 1) {
            window.location("profile.php");

        }
    },
    error: function(resultData) {
        alert(resultData);
    },
    failed: function() {
        alert("hello");
    }
  });
 }
```

Comment: You don't seem to have asked a question. You've quoted an error message, but that error tells you exactly what you need to do.

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin — It's obvious and blocking, so is often useful.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about your profile.php page?

Comment: profile.php is the page where user is redirected after login.

Comment: I want to know if values are filled in my textboxes by the first function and then i am fetching those values from second function and making ajax call to my service then why this error is occuring. because in my second function there is nothing to do with google api call.

Comment: What is the error from `This function gives error when called by submit button click`? Since you get the info from Google+ the error you highlight is likely ignorable.

Comment: the error is as mentioned above- Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost" from accessing a frame with origin "https://apis.google.com". The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.

Answer (score 1):

As your error message says:

> The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.

So, change the protocol that you're using.